# Why does had seem to be mandatory here

Tags: past-tense

I have  had replies to this question but none of them explained me why !!

"I wasn't expecting you to contact me again!!
I **(had)** tried to contact you so many times and did not receive an answer that I had completely forgotten that I had made an order.I was surprised to receive your email today

1°Would like to know why "had" seems to be mandatory here

The meaning is not very clear . It is not because I was surprised to receive an email today that I had tried to contact him before . To make sure it was before "had" seems to me obligatory (but I may be wrong). If it is the case can somebody explain me why!!!!

2 ° Does it convey the meaning : that first I made an order , then tried to email the seller without any luck(did not answer) then had forgotten this order until I received this message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation in (2) seems correct to me.

The speaker was not expecting to hear from their correspondent again because they had *earlier* tried repeatedly to contact them, without success. The enquiries were about an order, which the speaker had since forgotten about until they received this message.

Comment: what about one mandatory or not  Your answer makes me think that first had (had tried) is needed to make sure the attempt was before  getting the message.

Comment: Exactly - that's why I said 'they had _earlier_ tried to contact [the correspondent]'. I wouldn't say it was mandatory, but it certainly makes the sequence of events clearer.